# Boyd & Vandenberghe, Exercise 2.15g — Convexity of a region on the probability simplex

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, variance, geometric-probability

Exercise 2.15g of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook):

> On the probability simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where each point $p = (p_1, p_2, p_3, \ldots, p_n)$ corresponds to a distribution for random variable $X$ to take one of $n$ values: $\mathbb{P}(X = a_i) = p_i$ where $a_j < a_k$ for $j < k$. Is the region where $\mbox{Var}(X)\geq\alpha$ for some positive $\alpha$ a convex region or not?

This has a [solution](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/hw1sol.pdf) on the Stanford SEE course material of Prof Boyd's course but I didn't follow the reasoning. Would appreciate help on the answer.

Comment: What do you call probability simplex? Do you mean the convex hull of $(n+1)$ random points where the distribution of each point is the one described in your question? In this case are the distributions independent?

Comment: What is $Var(X)$?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2847156/339790)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small misprint in the solution which is not important for the main idea but may have confused you.
$\text{Var}(X)\geq\alpha$ is equivalent to
$$\boldsymbol{-}\sum_i^n a_i^2 p_i+\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i p_i\right)^2\leq\alpha$$
(in the correction the minus does not appear but that actually does not change the rest of the proof).

Now if we set $b_i=a_i^2$ and $A=aa^T$, the last equality can be written
$$-b^T p + p^T A p\leq \alpha.$$
The matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite so $p\mapsto -b^T p + p^T A p$ is convex (*e.g.* see example 3.2. page 71 of the textbook). And that implies that the solution of the above inequation is a convex set.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. Will take a look soon.