# Proving that the probabilities for which the variance of a distribution is greater than some number is convex

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, variance

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf#page=92&zoom=100,214,406), exercise 2.15 (f) and (g) — I am following along with the solutions from [here](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf).

> **2.15** *Some sets of probability distributions.* Let $x$ be a real-valued random variable with $\textbf{prob}(x = a_i) = p_i, i = 1,\dots, n$, where $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_n$. Of course $p \in {\bf R}^n$ lies in the standard probability simplex $P = \left\{ p \mid \mathbf{1}^T p = 1, p \succeq 0 \right\}$. Which of the following conditions are convex in $p$? (That is, for which of the following conditions is the set of $p \in P$ that satisfy the condition convex?)

---

For (f) and (g), the questions relate to the variance, where

$$\operatorname{var} (x) = {\Bbb E} (x^2) - {\Bbb E} (x)^2$$

and

$${\Bbb E} (x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_ip_i}$$

(f) asks whether $var(x) \le \alpha$ is a sufficient condition for convexity

(g) asks whether $var(x) \ge \alpha$ is a condition sufficient for convexity

In the solutions, the logic for why (f) is not convex makes sense to me, but the logic for why (g) is convex does not. The solution claims that the constraint in (g) is equivalent to:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i^2p_i} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_ip_i}\right)^2 = b^Tp + p^TAp \le \alpha$$

and thus must be convex because $aa^t$ is positive semidefinite (and presumably adding the convex positive semidefinite cone to the projection along the probabilities maintains the convexity?), but I do not understand how they jumped straight to that from:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i^2p_i} - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_ip_i}\right)^2 = b^Tp - p^TAp \ge \alpha$$

implied by

$$\operatorname{var} (x) = {\Bbb E} \left( x^2 \right) - {\Bbb E} (x)^2 \ge \alpha$$

Shouldn't it instead be

$$ p^T A p - b^T p \le \alpha$$

and no longer guarantee convexity in $p$?

Comment: [Listed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/613516/339790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go over the derivation again. We have
\begin{align*}
\text{var}(x) & = E(x^2) - (E(x))^2\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2 p_i - \Big( \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i p_i \Big)^2\\
& = b^T p - p^T A p,
\end{align*}
where $b = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1^2\\
\vdots\\
a_n^2
\end{bmatrix}$, $A = aa^T$.

So $\text{var}(x) \geq \alpha$ is equivalent to $p^T A p - b^T p \leq -\alpha$. (I don't know why the solution manual wrote $b^T p + p^T A p \leq \alpha$. It seems like a sign mistake to me. Nevertheless, it does not affect the conclusion.)

Define function $f(p) = p^T A p - b^T p$. The important point is that since $A = aa^T$ is positive semidefinite, $f(p)$ is a convex function (see Chapter 3 of your book). $\{p \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \  f(p) \leq -\alpha \}$ is a sublevel set of a convex function, which must be convex.

So the set of probabilities $p$ satisfying $\text{var}(x) \geq \alpha$ is $\{p \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ f(p) \leq -\alpha\} \cap \{p \ | \ \mathbf{1}^T p = 1, p \succeq 0\}$. This is a convex set.

Comment: I can see why we know that $p^TAp$ is convex, but since the linear combination with $b^Tp$ includes a nonpositive weight is that still a guarantee of convexity?

I suppose we can just as easily subsume the negative into $b$ and convert that into being $b = [-a_1^2..a_n^2]$ and it once again becomes a positive linear combination of convex functions, is that the route you take to prove that $p^TAp - b^Tp$ is convex? Maybe that's what the solutions manual did but left out all the explanation.

Comment: @Lev Avakian Simple. The term $-b^T p$ is linear. Adding a linear function to a convex function always gives you another convex function.